# jQuery going back 2 tags in order to change style css when no ID is available

Tags: jquery

Hey all I am trying to get the last tag going back 2 places. The current code I have trying to do this is:

```
//Setting the tag that has "This is an example" as a title to display none:
$('[title^="This is an example"]').css({'display':'none'});

//Adding an ID to the DIV:
$('[title^="This is an example"]').attr('id', 'TimeID');

//Getting that ID back from the DIV:
TimeID = $('[title^="This is an example"]').attr('id');

//Placing "<div>TESTING!</div>" before the TimeID DIV:
$("<div>TESTING!</div>").insertBefore('#' + TimeID);

//From the id of TimeID, go back 2 tags:
var curr = $('#' + TimeID).prev().prev();

//On that previous 2nd tag, read the Style of it (it does not have an ID)
//to make sure (currently as a test) that we got the correct tag which should
//output to the console "height: 100%; background-color: #fff;":
console.log($('#' + curr).attr('style'));
```

Using the code above, it gives me this:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]

The HTML I am trying to parse backwards from is this:

```
<div class="first_style" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;">
        <div style="width: 1px;"></div>
        <div style="height: 100%; background-color: #fff;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; position: relative; text-align: center; font-size: 10px; color: #fff;">
        <div>TESTING!</div>
        <a target="_new" href="http://zzzzz.com" id="TimeID" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;">5:54 PM</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the **DIV** of:

```
<div style="width: auto; height: 100%; background-color: #fff;"></div>
```

And since it has no ID I am unable just to call it by $('#[id here]).attr('style'). That is why I am needing to go back 2 tags in order to get its value (and to ultimately change it's style to something else).

Comment: Your `curr` is object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. `prev()` gives you the previous DOM element IN the same parent. 
For your selector you have to go up to the parent previous' div last child.

```
 var curr = $('div', $('#TimeID').parent().prev()).last();
```

You should rethink your html structure, your selectors shouldn't be that complex.

Comment: I get an *undefined* when trying your code. I also tried it with adding another **.prev()** and still doesn't seem to find it.

Comment: That gives me **<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;">** and not the **<div style="width: auto; height: 100%; background-color: #fff;"></div>** that I need.

Comment: updated the answer, your TimeID was the problem. jsfiddle.net/ktsvu9hg

Comment: Your update fetches **<div style="width: 1px;"></div>** and not the needed **<div style="width: auto; height: 100%; background-color: #fff;"></div>**

Comment: Thanks for the help, Loyalty Technology.

Comment: pretty sure .parent().prev().last()  is exactly what I put in my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//From the id of TimeID, go back 2 tags:
var curr = $('#' + TimeID).parent().prev();
```

this will give you the previous parent , then you would do `.find()` or last-of-type , or last() , or whatever you want to do to identify the last one , maybe give it a unique class or something